# Customize Salesforce login screen

Tags: customization

Our client would like to customize the Salesforce login page style (fonts, login button color) to make it similar to other forms (in communities, website). I know we can customize the logo, background color, right frame content.

Can someone give me an idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Have you seen the [Customize Your Community's Login Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=5) help document? Are you stuck someplace in the process of customizing the login flow?

Comment: My query was more on Salesforce login flow, not on the Community. From @sfdcfox's response I think customization is limited as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is found in Setup > Company Settings > My Domain. Here, you can customize the Header Logo, Right Frame, and Background Color. These are the only three settings you can set at this point in time. Obviously, it only works if your users go to `https://whateveryourdomain.my.salesforce.com` to log in. It also requires you to enable My Domain, since it would be impossible for Salesforce to know what presentation it should use before the user has logged in.